# Where is the best place to tell people about free online history courses?

Tags: discussion

Several [MOOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massive_open_online_course) providers now offer free (to audit*) history courses. For example, Coursera has a free, 7-week, online course from Wesleyan University on [The Ancient Greeks](https://www.coursera.org/learn/ancient-greeks) starting tomorrow (4 September 2017).

I'm sure that some users of History:SE would be interested in these courses, but what is the best way to let people know that they are available. I've posted about the Ancient Greeks course on [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39790862#39790862), but - let's be honest -how many History:SE users ever actually visit the [forum](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1560/the-time-machine).

This kind of post really doesn't seem to me like the sort of thing that we should be posting on the main site and, to be honest, I'm not at all sure that it's really suited to meta either.

That just seems to leave the forum. Or am I missing something?

---

* i.e. you don't get a certificate.

Comment: Excellent question! Futurelearn has similar MOOC courses - currently a "virtual tour" of Ancient Rome.

Comment: @TheHonRose They also have a course on Portus (the port of ancient Rome) and another one on underwater archaeology from the University of Southampton which are excellent courses. (I should declare an interest in the latter - I know some of the teaching team! ;-)  )